# Installing ROS2 : E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages

Tags: package-management, software-installation, ros

I'm not an expert in linux and just a beginner in ROS. I need to install this version of ros : ROS 2 Foxy Fitzroy (https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Installation.html)

On my linux computer :

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

And I'm having some issues with the command : `sudo apt install ros-foxy-desktop`
Giving me this error :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-foxy-desktop : Depends: ros-foxy-action-tutorials-cpp but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: ros-foxy-action-tutorials-interfaces but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: ros-foxy-action-tutorials-py but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: ros-foxy-composition but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: ros-foxy-demo-nodes-cpp but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: ros-foxy-demo-nodes-cpp-native but it is not going to be 
                    Depends: ros-foxy-examples-rclcpp-minimal-client but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: ros-foxy-examples-rclcpp-minimal-composition but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: ros-foxy-examples-rclcpp-minimal-publisher but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: ros-foxy-examples-rclcpp-minimal-service but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: ros-foxy-examples-rclcpp-minimal-subscriber but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: ros-foxy-examples-rclcpp-minimal-timer but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: ros-foxy-tlsf-cpp but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: ros-foxy-topic-monitor but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: ros-foxy-turtlesim but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I've been trying for 2 days to find a fix with no clues.

Here are some commands I tried with their results:

```
sudo apt-get update --fix-missing && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

Hit:1 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                             
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB]                                           
Hit:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                  
Hit:5 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                        
Hit:6 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease                                                     
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease [74.6 kB]                                         
Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88.7 kB]                                          
Hit:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                              
Ign:10 http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu disco InRelease                              
Hit:11 http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu disco Release     
Hit:12 http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu focal InRelease
Fetched 252 kB in 3s (89.0 kB/s)                          
Reading package lists... Done
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

`sudo dpkg --configure -a`
shows nothing

`dpkg --get-selections | grep hold`
shows nothing

If you have any suggestion I would gladly try it.

Thank you for anyone who took the time to read my message !

Comment: bionic is Ubuntu 18.04 - those repos will not work on Ubuntu 20.04 (which is focal) Removing the bionic repos should solve your problem. Note that you can **not** install bionic software on focal.

Comment: Thank you so much, You send me on the right way and indeed, removing bionic solved a lot of my issues !